# Error/Exception with parameters

Tags: python, exception, parameters

I would like to know how I can throw exceptions / errors to say that a parameter is null or its not in the .txt file that works as a dictionnary.

The dictionnary it's like that:

```
"""rule:parameter:value"""
aa:alfa:1
bba:beta:15
```

I got this for the moment:

```
def get(rule_name,parameter_name):
    try:
        with open("parameters.txt", "r") as infile:   
            for line in infile:                 
                if line.startswith(rule_name.lower()) and line.split(":")[1] == parameter_name.lower():      
                    return line.split(":")[2]   
    except Value:
        print "Error"


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(get("aa","alfa")) #return the value associated to the rule and the parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Just raise a value error

```
raise ValueError("you parameter is null or in wrong format")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert` with an error message

```py
assert arg is not None, "Parameter is null"
```

If the assertion fails, an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) with the error message will be raised.